# What's the difference between the two English words "liquid" and "fluid"?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between the two English words "liquid" and "fluid"?

For example, "US liquid gallon" vs "US fluid ounce". 
Can we also say "fluid gallon" and "liquid ounce", too?

Thanks in advance. Have a good weekend to you all.

Comment: Have you checked with a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

"fluid ounce" is the name for a standard unit of measure and it would not appropriate to substitute "fluid" for "liquid".

Typically "fluid" describes something which flows and it could be [a liquid or a gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter).  Therefore it would be best not to treat the words as synonymous.

Confusingly, in finance, "liquidity" is used to describe how quickly/easily an asset can be bought or sold for cash.  The term "fluidity" is not used.

In energy "liquefied petroleum gas" is commonly called "liquid petroleum gas" (at least in the UK).  It is burnt as a gas at atmospheric pressure to produce useful energy as heat but it is stored in its liquid state in a pressurised container.  "Fluid Petroleum Gas" gas would not make sense because gas is already a fluid.

Comment: But ***fluidity*** IS used - both literally, as per M-W's definition: [*the physical property of a substance that enables it to flow,*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fluidity) and *metaphorically*, as per one of their cited use cases: *Emily Noël sings both works with an alluring clarity and **fluidity,** qualities that Ms. Krash matches at the keyboard.* I'd also just mention that in the UK at least, ***lighter fluid*** can mean ***liquid gas*** (but only when it's *petrol* - you wouldn't want to fill your Zippo with liquid butane or propane! :)